# Prevent Network Settings From Changing Automatically

Tags: macos, network, wifi, security, proxy

How can I stop Network Settings from being able to change without my permission? Couldn't find anything under "Security" in Settings.

---

OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

**Changes (broke Internet):** Settings -> Network -> Advanced

1. TCP/IP -> Configure IPv6: "Link-local only" (vs. "Automatically")
2. Proxies -> Web Proxy (HTTP) *Checked* (vs. *Unchecked*)

Running *TunnelBear VPN* (which turns off IPv6 automatically to prevent leakage when using "Vigilant" mode) and *UBlock Origin*. I suspect they may have something to do with changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure the issue was with TunnelBear.